# Efficent way to store "180-bit" (more than 64-bit) integer

Tags: java, performance, bit-manipulation, java-8

I am using bits to represent events which occur on a day. For instance if I store 4 days of information I could use 1011 (staring from right to left) would indicate on days 1,2, and 4 events occurred (bit 1,2, and 4 are set).

I am using the type of `Long` to store the bits (which would in this example store the number 11). Now with `Long` I could store 63 days of events (long max size is 2^64 -1).

FYI: I later take one on my sets of events and then compare it with another set to see  how many events occurred on the same day (I use Long's bitcount method to do this). For example, `1011 AND 1000 = 1` event occurred on the same day in these two sets.

he problem I am facing is: I now need to store more than 63 days of data. I need about 180 days now. I am facing performance issues with my two solutions and was wondering if there is a more efficient way to essentially store a "180-bit" Integer.

My first solution was to use `BigInteger`, but this is very slow when running. My other solution is to breakup the 180 bits into 3 `Long`s and later compare accordingly, but obviously this creates 3 times the work.

Comment: How about java.util.BitSet

Comment: First of all I dont understand your method of storing, and secondly  break it to three Long dont make it three time slower.

Comment: In terms of primitives your choices are between the various integer data types.  One way or another you need to "splice" values together to get 180 bits.  (Note:  It might be wise to avoid using `boolean[]` as the Oracle versions I've seen implement boolean arays as byte arrays with one bit per byte.)  Otherwise use java.util.BitSet or another Set implementation.  (You are talking about manipulating sets, after all.)

Comment: What if something happened on the 3rd or 5th day etc? That would be misinterpreted as something happening on the 1st and 2nd, or 4th and 1st day respectively. I suggest using a boolean array for this instead.

Comment: @YvesDaoust -- I only recall 36-bit LOGICALs (I think), on the 7094.  But, come to think of it, I think the CDC 6600 (which I also used) had 60-bit LOGICALs.  The thing about Java is even the `boolean` *arrays* are one bit per byte, in the Sun/Oracle implementation (as it existed a few years back, at least).  Very inefficient for storing bit sets.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - But anyone with any sense knew not to use LOGICAL arrays (if the compiler even supported them).  Would not be the case for someone using Java today, since the sense of what's going on with the hardware has been lost.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Ah, but everyone knew the work-arounds.  (Of course, don't ask me what they are, since I haven't coded FORTRAN since 1974.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### [java.util.BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)

BitSet is part of the standard library and is suitable for your Use-case. But maybe you should look also at the second option below which is a compressed alternative. Which is supposed to be much more memory and performance efficient.

Using the standard library you could define something like

```
BitSet bits1 = new BitSet(180);
```

Even if you store more than 180 bits you can resize it at any point of time.

If you want to compare it with a other set you can do something like this:

```
BitSet bits1 = new BitSet(180);
BitSet bits2 = new BitSet(180);
// do something here to set events

// find events which happened on the same day in bits1 and bits2
bits1.and(bits2);
```

and then you can traverse the set using something like [nextSetBit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#nextSetBit%28int%29). An example from Oracle documentation to traverse over all events which occur in `bits1` and `bits2` would be then:

```
for (int i = bits1.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = bits1.nextSetBit(i+1)) {
     // operate on index i here
}
```

### Compressed Bitset JavaEWAH

see: [Github repository for javaewah](https://github.com/lemire/javaewah)

Alternative to Java BitSet used in some Big-Data projects like Apache Hive and Apache Spark.

Example with JavaEWAH:

```
EWAHCompressedBitmap eventsBitmap1 = EWAHCompressedBitmap.bitmapOf(
    0,1,22,64,1<<30);
EWAHCompressedBitmap eventsBitmap2 = EWAHCompressedBitmap.bitmapOf(
    1,3,64,1<<30);
System.out.println("Events 1: "+eventsBitmap1);
System.out.println("Events 2: "+eventsBitmap2);
```

Find events which happened on the same day

```
EWAHCompressedBitmap bothEventsBitmap = eventsBitmap1.and(eventsBitmap2);
System.out.println("Days where both events took place: "+bothEventsBitmap);
```

### Further implementations

- [Roaring Bitmap](https://github.com/lemire/RoaringBitmap), also a compressed bitmap implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have never heard of JavaEWAH but will have a look and try to implement it!

Comment: Doing a little bit of research I noticed another alternative, RoaringBitmap. I will try to do a little benchmarking, but if anyone knew generally which one is faster already that would be great to know!

Comment: @user2924127 I add the RoaringBitmap to the answer.

Comment: roaring bitmap only support 2^32-1 for one object

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need arbitrary precision and you can use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) which provides *immutable arbitrary-precision integers* for that,

```
BigInteger val = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE).add(BigInteger.ONE);
System.out.println(val);
```

Output is

```
9223372036854775808
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sets of bits are sparse, explicit enumeration of the 'ones' can be advantageous (in your example case, you store the integers 1, 2 and 4 as three bytes, preceded by a count or followed by a terminator byte -> n ones (=3) require n+1 bytes (=4) instead of 23.

As long as the average number of ones is smaller than 23, this representation is more compact. Depending on the operations you perform, it can be slower or faster.

Anyway, handling a variable length representation can be difficult, especially if it is dynamic.

The explicit bit set representation is often preferred, but if your distribution of events calls for it, a mixed representation is also possible (enumeration for, say, 10 ones or less, bits set otherwise).

In the terrible cases where you need a more compact representation, Huffman entropy coding can help you compress by a further factor 2 or 3.